# Backlight adjustment buttons on Thinpad T495 don't work

Tags: linux, acpi, backlight

I don't see any events when I run `xev` and press either the brightness up or down keys.

I have configured i3wm to handle the `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp`, but they won't get triggered because they are never published.

Using the brillo command to change the brightness from the command-line works great as a workaround, but it is really nice to be able to use the keys instead.

I'm running Arch Linux with kernel version 5.14.12-arch1-1.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is several parts:

- set the `acpi_backlight=vendor` [parameter on the kernel command-line](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/kernel_parameters)
- install, enable, and start the [ACPI event daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/acpid). It can be enabled and started with `sudo systemctl enable --now acpid.service`.

  - on Arch Linux, it can be installed with `sudo pacman -S acpid`

And create a set of files like these:

`/etc/acpi/events/ideapad-monitor-brightness-up`:

```
event=video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
action=/usr/bin/brillo -A 5 -u 60000
```

`/etc/acpi/events/ideapad-monitor-brightness-down`:

```
event=video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
action=/usr/bin/brillo -U 5 -u 60000
```

The event handlers for `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` can be deleted. The events still won't come through, but that's fine since there's a separate set of event handlers in the acpid configuration directory.

You can also choose to use something other than brillo to do this if you'd prefer.